# Android Studio new line when editing resource file

Tags: android, android-studio

Let's say I have the following `TextView`:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the past when I wanted to add a new attribute I would put the cursor before /> hit enter and the cursor would move to the next align aligned with the start of the previous line. Now for some reason when I hit enter it goes to the next line but to the start of the file, it doesn't indent automatically, which is pretty annoying. I hit enter and the new line appears like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="text"/>
```

What's going on? I did change the version of Android Studio. I was running the stable one but decided to try the beta.

Comment: Did you check if you have any errors in the layout. Or is it something that is happening all the time no matter what layout you are editting?

Comment: @Juan It happens even with the fresh project after restart. Okay I think I solved the problem. Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Set from... -> Kotlin. I'm not sure why it doesn't have XML but setting it as Kotlin solved the problem.

Comment: @dfasdflskladf, then answer your own question and accept that

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Set from... -> Kotlin solved the problem.